# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to push the 'currentBall'  object into the 'currentOver.balls' array

```
$scope.currentOver.balls.push($scope.currentBall);
```

The current state of both objects just before the above code is run (from the dev tools):

```
$scope.currentOver: Array[1]
0: Object
balls: Array[0]
bowlerId: 0
byes: 0
legByes: 0
noBalls: 0
runs: 0
wickets: 0
wides: 0
__proto__: Object
length: 1
overId: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

$scope.currentBall: Object
ballId: 0
batsmanId: 0
bowlerId: 0
byes: 0
legByes: 0
noBalls: 0
runs: 2
wicketsNumber: 0
wicketsType: 0
wides: 0
__proto__: Object
```

I get an error: `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. But it's clear that the '$scope.currentOver.balls' array is defined, so what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your quoted "current state" because I suspect important indentation has been lost, but it *looks* like `currentOver`, being an array, *contains* an entry with a `balls` property (rather than having a `balls` property of its own). So:

```
$scope.currentOver[0].balls.push($scope.currentBall);
```

The key bits that make me think that are:

```
$scope.currentOver: Array[1] <== Here, we're seeing that it's an array with one entry
0: Object                    <== This looks like it's about to show us what that entry is
balls: Array[0]              <== And so I suspect this is in the entry, not the array
bowlerId: 0
...
```

E.g., I suspect the lost indentation probably looks something like this:

```
$scope.currentOver: Array[1]
    0: Object
        balls: Array[0]
        bowlerId: 0
...
```

Comment: Ah, of course - that makes sense. Actually I don't want `currentOver` to be an array, rather an object. Thanks very much for your help